error in msnodesqlv8 coming from begin function at query-handler: Parameter 2: Invalid parameter type
Im kinda a newbie so sorry in advance for the dumb question.
so i have this 2 functions:
const sql = require('msnodesqlv8');
const { rows } = require('mssql');

async searchThings(){
  try {
    const result = await querySelect("SELECT * FROM Things");
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }

}

async function querySelect(query) {


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
  
          resolve(rows);
        }
      });
    });
}

It always works when i just fetch things, i have other functions that add things, edit things, and delete things. They all work.
The trouble is when i edit a Thing (and i can see on the database that it was edited) this searchThings gives me an "Uncaught Error Error: IMNOD: [msnodesql] Parameter 2: Invalid parameter type" at begin function in query-handler from msnodesqlv8.
Weirdest thing is i have a Table "Other Things" with all the same code just different names and it works perfectly.
